# Can't set the color of the progressbar from Fabric UI

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm trying to set the color of the progressbar from fabricUI. I trying to use the style attribuut, but it doesn't have this attribuut. Trought the attribuut className I'm able to set the background, it seems it doesn't not accept the foreground style.

Also tried putting it in a div, but that also doesn't work.